# Spring Injection fails with a couple of Maven projects

Tags: java, spring, maven-3

I have two projects built with Maven. The first project deals with persistence aspects, while the second deals with business aspects and this last one has to use the first project for persist data. I'm using Spring data jpa for the first project and Spring mvc 4 for the second.

I need to configure the second project, in the way that, the second project can use the first project using the dependency injection through Spring annotations. So I mean, in the first project I have the Spring JpaRepository interfaces in a jar, and I want to use them in the second project using @Autowired annotation. I'm using the next configuration:

First Project pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact_id</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Second Project pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>group.two</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact_two</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!-- second project dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifact_id</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

As you can see, the first project compiles as a jar while the second project compiles as a war. In the pom of the second project, you can see that I have a dependency over first project:

```
 <!-- second project dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact_id</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem comes when I try to inject any @Services or @Component in the second project from the first project, because I get a dependency injection error:

> GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a': Injection of autowired dependencies failed...: No qualifying bean of type b found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency...

This error is present in bean that tries to inject an @Services from the first project.

I think the error is in the Maven projects dependency, but already I've tried with many things that I found with searching the web, but nothing works.

My first spring project configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd">


    <!-- Database configuraction -->
    <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sch2db"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
       <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitSHC2"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
       <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- JPA Repositories -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.sergio.SCH2.persistence.repositories"></jpa:repositories>

</beans>
```

My second spring project configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment and your base-package here: -->
         <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.sergio.SCH2.service"/>


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->`enter code here`
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem related to `groupId` you have set for your first project.

According to documentation  :- [maven naming convention](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html), `groupId` should be named as the package structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've wrote the <groupId> as group.id for ilustrative purposes in the exposition of question, but already I have the same group id like package name structure in both pom files.
If you have another idea about what could be the problem, I'll be thankful with you.

Comment: can you post your spring configuration(XML file) for the second project and first project both?

Comment: Hi RE350 I just posted the spring configuration for both projects

Comment: Just to confirm, your first project is Spring JPA and second is Spring MVC,and you want to inject dependency of second in first????

Comment: Yes, the first project is a Spring JPA and the second is Spring MVC. My wish is to inject annotated classes (Spring @Services, @Compnent) from first project into the second project.